# Invalid object when call createOrGetStripeCustomer

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

When calling the createOrGetStripeCustomer() function in Cashier's Stripe integration, I get an "Invalid object" error.

Here's my Billable model:

```php
/**
 * Get the customer address that should be synced to Stripe.
 */
public function stripeAddress(): string|null
{
    return $this->address_line1 . ' ' . $this->address_line2 . ' ' . $this->postal_code . ' ' . $this->country;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The stripeAddress() function must return an array, as explained in the documentation

```php
/**
 * Get the customer address that should be synced to Stripe.
 */
public function stripeAddress(): array|null
{
    return [
        'city' => $this->city,
        'country' => $this->country,
        'line1' => $this->address_line1,
        'line2' => $this->address_line2,
        'postal_code' => $this->postal_code
    ];
}
```